# Выдает ошибку error: conflicting types

Tags: c

Выдает ошибку error: conflicting types for 'thread_create_dop' tid_t thread_create_dop(const char *name, int priority, thread_func *function, void *aux, int cpu_burst)
Не знаю, что делать, помогите, пожалуйста

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "threads/init.h"
#include "threads/interrupt.h"
#include "threads/thread.h"

void thread_function(void *aux) {
    int ticks_worked = 0;
    while (true) {
        printf("Working... Process Name: %s\n", thread_current()->name);
        
        ticks_worked++;

        if (ticks_worked % 10 == 0) {
            printf("Process %s has worked for %d ticks.\n", thread_current()->name, ticks_worked);
        }

        thread_yield(); // Передача управления
    }
}

tid_t thread_create_dop(const char *name, int priority, thread_func *function, void *aux, int cpu_burst);

tid_t thread_create_dop(const char *name, int priority, thread_func *function, void *aux, int cpu_burst) {
    struct thread *t;
    tid_t tid;

    enum intr_level old_level = intr_disable();

    t = thread_create(name, priority, function, aux);
    if (t == NULL) {
        tid = TID_ERROR;
    } else {
        t->CPU_burst = cpu_burst; 
        tid = t->tid = allocate_tid();
    }

    intr_set_level(old_level);

    return tid;
}


int main(int argc UNUSED, char *argv[] UNUSED) {
    thread_set_priority(PRI_MAX);

    tid_t tid1 = thread_create_dop("Thread1", 63, thread_function, NULL, 10);
    tid_t tid2 = thread_create_dop("Thread2", 63, thread_function, NULL, 15);
    tid_t tid3 = thread_create_dop("Thread3", 63, thread_function, NULL, 20); 

    thread_set_priority(PRI_MIN);

    while (true) {
        printf("Thread running: %s, CPU Burst remaining: %d\n", thread_current()->name, thread_current()->CPU_burst);
        if (--thread_current()->CPU_burst <= 0) {
            break;
        }
        thread_yield(); // Передача управления другому готовому процессу
    }

    // Ожидание завершения выполнения всех созданных процессов
    while (!thread_all_finished()) {
        thread_yield(); // Передаем управление другому готовому процессу
    }

    return 0;
}
```